# Conditional ng-click on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code inside `ng-repeat`

```
<tr ng-repeat="location in assetLocations track">     
    <span class="fa fa-remove fa-lg text-danger" style="cursor: pointer;"
                        ng-show="location.isEdit"
                        ng-click="readOnly===false ? (cancel();location.isEdit = false; updateClicked = false;) : null"></span>
</tr>
```

Here `location.isEdit` property is set on the fly.

I want to set a conditional ng-click to `span`. But the code above gives the following error

> > angular.js:11598 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ';' is unexpected, >>expecting [)] at column 29 of the expression [readOnly===false ? >>(cancel();location.isEdit = false; updateClicked = false;) : null] starting at >>[;location.isEdit = false; updateClicked = false;) : null].

I can set the variables inside the function, but I need to set the variables and call the functions on `ng-click`

How to use the conditional ng-click for this type of scenario?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like the below code,

**Controller**:

```
$scope.conditionCancelClick = function(location){
    if(!$scope.readOnly){
        $scope.cancel();
        location.isEdit = false;
        $scope.updateClicked = false;
    }
}
```

**Template:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="location in assetLocations track">  
    <span class="fa fa-remove fa-lg text-danger" style="cursor: pointer;" 
          ng-show="location.isEdit" ng-click="conditionCancelClick(location)"></span>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing ; to , as

```html
<tr ng-repeat="location in assetLocations track">     
    <span class="fa fa-remove fa-lg text-danger" style="cursor: pointer;"
                        ng-show="location.isEdit"
                        ng-click="readOnly===false ? (cancel(),location.isEdit 
= false, updateClicked = false) : null"></span>
</tr>
```